# Require_once In laravel

Tags: php, laravel, require-once

I have a plugin for my site and I duplicate the folder structure and renamed the files, I try to load the new plugin I made in the global.php file the same way the original plugin loaded with

```
//load plugins
if(File::exists(public_path('plugins/releasedate/protected/start.php')))
{
File::requireOnce(public_path('plugins/releasedate/protected/start.php'));
}
```

But when I'm adding the other plugin

```
//load plugins
if(File::exists(public_path('plugins/releasedate/protected/start.php')))
{
File::requireOnce(public_path('plugins/releasedate/protected/start.php'));
}

if(File::exists(public_path('plugins/streaming/protected/start.php')))
{
File::requireOnce(public_path('plugins/streaming/protected/start.php'));
}
```

It load's only the first plugin. Or can I use only one requireOnce in my script?

Comment: So if you flip the order of the ifs the `streaming` plugin will load?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, the plugin will load, but not the other

Comment: Any particular reason why you are putting your plugin code (especially PHP) inside a publicly accessible location (`public_path`)?

Comment: Im using a buyed script and the devolper created a plugin for this script, I think thats the reason why.

Comment: The plugin if im using both is not working correctly, the releasedatedashboard controller is not working anymore. I Update my question with more description

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$plugins = array(
    public_path('plugins/releasedate/protected/start.php'),
    public_path('plugins/streaming/protected/start.php')
);

foreach($plugins AS $plugin) {
    if(!is_file($plugin)) {
        die("NO FILE: ".$plugin);
    }

    require_once($plugin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I merged my files without a plugin folder and start.php file and everything seems to be fine. Thank you all